# web.config allow all users from a specific domain, but not another

Tags: iis, dns, web-config

I have users from two different domains that can access the web site I am currently working on and I would like to only allow users from one of those domain to access the site. I've done some research and the only thing I was able to come up with is allowing users from a specific domain group, but not from an entire domain only.

I've also come across this post that suggest to check the domain manually upon logon:

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/343407-using-web-config-allow-access-domain-users-only

I've added this to the web.config, but it does not appear to be working:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="FirstDomain\Domain Users"/>
  <deny users="SecondDomain\Domain Users" />
</authorization>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Got it working eventually:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="FirstDomain\Domain Users"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 4):

"Allow" should preceed the "Deny" tags, as in your case, everything will be denied access.

```
<system.web>
 <authorization>
  <allow users="FirstDomain\Domain Users"/>
  <deny users="SecondDomain\Domain Users" />
 </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after amending the web.config file the restrictions still did not work. This was because on the website/application "Anonymous Authentication" needed to be disabled and "Windows Authentication" enabled.

To do so

- open IIS manager
- in the left had pane navigate to the website\application you want to restrict access to and click on it to highlight it
- In the right hand pane double-click Authentication

[image: Authentication location]

At this point you are now able to configure the authentication settings (as below) to whatever is relevant in the environment being configured:

[image]